# It's necessary to connect every React Component with redux even when using Provider?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

My app index start with:

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
       <Router history={browserHistory}>
           <Route path="/" component={App}>
               <IndexRoute component={Main} />
               <Route path="/search" component={MovieSearch} />
               <Route path="/movies" component={MovieList} />
           </Route>
       </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My Main.js:

`render() { return (<div>{this.props.children}</div> )}`

When I access URI: ***/movies*** MovieList props stay undefined until I connect the component to the store. Is this correct? I need to connect every component to the store to access state? I can't get props from Main parent props without this?

I really need to call mapStateToProps and sometimes mapDispatchToProps to access state and actions ?

This is the default/good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, **Yes**

Unless you have a `layout` component, you need to connect each component to work with `redux`.

You can take a look at [one of my project](https://github.com/praneshr/petch). I used [page.js](https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/) as my router. It is very simple and solves my purpose. For every route, I pass the name of the component to be rendered. So, a `layout` page will be loaded where I connect redux and pass the state as `props` to the child components. And based on the `render` passed by the `router`. I will render the component inside the `layout`.

Using `layout` is a very good practice. It becomes a common place where all your components gets rendered.

Useful links:

- [mapStateToProps in Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

**[Update]**

You should also take a look at [Redux Router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux)